# python: перевод списка строк и чисел в строку с экранированием символов

Tags: python, строки

есть список в котором содержатся строки и числа вида

```
arr = ['text1', "text2", 11, 15, 'text3']
```

на выходе требуется получить строку вида `'text1', 'text2', 11, 15, 'text3'`

при этом символ `'` должен быть заэкранирован

подскажите, можно ли это сделать одной командой (условно в 1 строку) или надо писать код вида:

```
q = ', '.join([str(elem) if type(elem) == int else "'" + elem.replace('\'', '\\\'') + "'" for elem in arr])
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так, используя функцию `repr`:

```py
arr = ['text1', "text2", 11, 15, 'text3']
result = ', '.join(list(map(repr, arr)))
print(repr(result))
```

Выводит:

```
"'text1', 'text2', 11, 15, 'text3'"
```

Comment: Можно еще проще, через `repr(arr)[1:-1]`

Comment: супер! но на `"a ' b"` будет проблема - потому что на выходе все таки нужно 'a \' b', т.е. строка в одинарных кавычках